# React - How do I give each child component a unique ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a parent component that renders one of several child components:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const activeChild = this.state.activeChild; // 0, 1, 2, etc.
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children[activeChild]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Each of these child components needs to have a `ref` to its own unique DOM node. In my case, I need to pass each child's node to a third-party library to draw something on it (for example: a visualization, a canvas, or a map).

The problem is that, when the child components are rendered to the same 'point' in the React tree, at different times, they all end up sharing the same `ref`. (I think)

[Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem, using Leaflet.js.](https://jsfiddle.net/ztzwbxhu/8/)

When all of the children are rendered separately, they each get their own DOM node to draw their map onto. But when they are shown one-at-a-time, only the first one is able to draw onto the `ref`'d DOM node.

Can I tell React to use (and display) separate nodes for each individual child's `ref`, even if the children are being mounted at the same point?

If not, is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: give each child a unique [`key`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) parameter: `<SimpleMap key="New York City" name={"New York City"} pos={ [ 40.725467, -73.996744 ] } />`

Comment: This worked, thanks!

I had read the "Lists and Keys" section of the React documentation, but it never occurred to me that multiple children are still treated as "siblings" even if only one of them is being rendered at a time.

Comment: A ref if a reference to a component or element in React. A key is a unique identifier to every single element in the DOM. When you render multiple items in an array you have to assign a key because react cannot auto assign keys that aren't explicitly written out in the render method.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ref the [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and not the [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html), try something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  ...
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
   }
  render() {
    const activeChild = this.state.activeChild; // 0, 1, 2, etc.
    const ChildComponent = this.props.children[activeChild];

    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent ref={this.myRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I did not test this.